# Python: how to set TkInter attribute from submodule?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using TkInter to show a GUI dialog under Python 2.7.

I've defined the GUI in the main module, and I trying the split off the logic to a separate module that I import.

```
import sys

from Tkinter import *
import ttk

import dialoglogic

       :
       :

class processorDialog:
    def _init__(self, top=None):
           :
           :
        self.ButtonProcess = Button(top)
        self.ButtonProcess.configure( state=DISABLED)
        self.ButtonProcess.configure( text='''Start Process''')
```

And now in the dialoglogic module, I need to set the state of the button to NORMAL.

I know I need to use

```
xxxx.ButtonProcess.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

But I've been unable to determine the secret sauce for "xxxx" to access the TkI button widget in the parent module from the child module.

If the answer is out there, I'm confused as to how to Google it because I'm not coming up with any results (yet it seems like something everyone would need to do at some point ;-)  )

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Presumably, at some point you actually construct an instance of `processorDialog`.  Possibly, you store a reference to that instance somewhere - perhaps a global variable, or an instance variable in some other class.  *That* reference is your `xxxx`.  If you didn't store it, you can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you're creating an instance of `processorDialog`.You need to save that, and *that* is your "xxxx":

```
xxxx = processorDialog()
...
xxxx.ButtonProcess.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

Though, purely from an OO point of view, it's a bit unusual for one class to modify the internal state of a component of another class. A better solution is to create a method in `processorDialog` for setting the state, and having your code call that.

Example:

```
class processorDialog:
    ...
    def enable_button():
        self.ButtonProcess.configure(state=NORMAL)

xxxx = processorDialog()
...
xxxx.enable_button()
```

---

As a final note, you seem to have the naming conventions backwards, which makes your code hard to read. Your class should begin with an uppercase (eg: `ProcessDialog`) and your instance variables should begin with a lowercase (eg: `self.buttonProcess`)

For more information on standard python conventions, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)